# Rails3: Git still thinks that I am on an old branch from a project that I terminated and restarted

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3

I was working on a rails 3 app that I screwed up and needed to start over.  At the time I was on a git branch named "skeleton".  I deleted everything in the folder and then started over by reinstalling a new rails app in the same old folder.  Then I went to github and deleted the repository.  After working on setting up the new app I went to do a git init and found out that git still thinks I am on the old skeleton branch.

How can I strip the old git branch from the current app so that I can run a new git init?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a branch use:

```
git branch -D branch_name
```

Where `branch_name` is the name of the branch you wish to delete. Make sure to checkout a new branch before you start as you cannot delete the branch you're currently on.

Here's the [doc page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html)

Answer (score 3):

From the root of your app directory:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then run git init as normal.

Comment: Yep, just remove the .git folder and it will no longer be a git repository at all. You can use it as if it were a brand new folder.